# Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm have this error in Unity and dont know how to solve it, all app except ads work well.

Anyone can help?

Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\ed4ng\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.temp\PackageOperation01' (Expected 'C:\Users\ed4ng\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat:FindNewestInstalledAndroidSDKVersion() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/UnityCompat.cs:372)
GooglePlayServices.UnityCompat:GetAndroidTargetSDKVersion() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/UnityCompat.cs:127)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:CanEnableJetifierOrPromptUser(String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:2418)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ResolveUnsafe(Action`1, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1668)
GooglePlayServices.<ScheduleResolve>c__AnonStorey5:<>m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1637)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ExecuteNextResolveJob() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1494)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:ScheduleResolve(Boolean, Boolean, Action`1, Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1650)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1156)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:m__8() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.wIfXvkCcwE/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1135)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecutePollingJobs() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.oShw7fyUik/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:409)
Google.RunOnMainThread:m__1() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.oShw7fyUik/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:541)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.oShw7fyUik/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested(Boolean) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.oShw7fyUik/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.oShw7fyUik/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:200)